# File not opening a second time in c++

Tags: c++, file

My code is split into task 1 and task 2. I want to open and close with each task to reset the pointer to the start position. I did try `fseek(OH-in.txt, 0, SEEK_SET)` instead of opening a second time but that didn't work.

The tasks don't matter just pay attention to where I open and close the file OH-in.txt.

The file only opens (and outputs data that was read) for the first task!

Here is my code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string collegeName;
    string location;
    int currentEnroll;
    int tuition;
    int numOfSchools = 0;  // edit this in code below
/* 

TASK 1

*/
    // TASK 1: list the schools and the tuition of the schools in Cincinnati with
    // tuition below 20,000
    ifstream file;
    file.open("OH-in.txt");

    vector<string> arr;  // declare array

    // read lines of OH-in.txt
    while (file >> collegeName >> location >> currentEnroll >> tuition) {
        // add collegeName and location to array if true
        if (tuition < 20000 && location == "Cincinnati") {
            collegeName = "(" + collegeName + " $" + to_string(tuition) + ") ";

            arr.push_back(collegeName);
            numOfSchools++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = arr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }

    cout << numOfSchools << " schools meet this criteria.";
    file.close();
/*


TASK 2

*/
    // TASK 2 Calculate and display the average tuition of schools with more than

    file.open("OH-in.txt");

    vector<string> arr2;

    double avgTuition = 0;
    int expensiveSchools = 0;

    // iterate through the list. If a school with enrollment higher than 10,000 is found, add tuition to total. It will later be divided by the total number of expensive schools.
    while (file >> collegeName >> location >> currentEnroll >> tuition) {
        if (currentEnroll > 10000) {
            avgTuition += tuition;
            expensiveSchools += 1;
        }
        if (collegeName == "BGSU") {
            cout << "BGSU Tuition: " << tuition << endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` - this is **not** how you get the size of a vector. It should be `arr.size() - 1`.

Comment: `int i = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` is totally wrong for computing the magnitude of a `std::vector`. That's what the `size()` member is for. And if you're going to *iterate* the vector in reverse, why use sizing at all; just use the reverse iterators `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

Comment: You're doing basically the same loop *twice*. You don't need that. Open the file once, read all the information from the file, and do *both* task 1 and task 2 using the same loop. And if `BGSU Tuition` needs to be printed later, then save it in another variable to print after the (one and only) loop. And talking about unneeded code, you don't need `arr2` either, even if you keep the second loop.

Comment: I will be doing a third task after so I would prefer to open and close files with each task, to stay organized.

Comment: Keep a break point check whether close returns 0 or something else

Comment: Fixing the vector size did not fix the issue? Hmm, I thought your program was just crashing at point.

Comment: When I add a cout >> "hello"; at the end of my program it works. So the program runs all the way through. I don't think the file opens a second time

Comment: @sdev> it is a good idea to stay organised. Push it one step further: make each task a separate function, and then your `main()` should only consist of `task1(); task2(); task3();`. This way each task has isolated variables… and you will see file will open correctly ;)

Comment: I made separate functions and it worked! Thanks